# Unable to populate custom fields in template from API

Tags: xml, soap, advanced-custom-fields, docusignapi, custom-fields

Docusign API V3 - I have a sandbox account, a template set up with custom fields. I have the soap xml code to create the envelope, attach the template (by ID) but I cannot figure out how to populate the custom fields before it is emailed. I have tried using both

```
          <CustomField>
            <Name>Custom Field List</Name>
            <Show>True</Show>
            <Required>True</Required>
            <Value />
            <CustomFieldType>List</CustomFieldType>
            <ListItems>One; Two; Three</ListItems>
          </CustomField>
        <CustomFields>
          <CustomField>
            <Name>FullName</Name>
            <Show>True</Show>
            <Required>True</Required>
            <Value>John W Smith</Value>
          </CustomField>
          <CustomField>
            <Name>Address</Name>
            <Show>True</Show>
            <Required>True</Required>
            <Value>123 Any Way Tempe, AZ 85082</Value>
            <CustomFieldType>List</CustomFieldType>
            <ListItems>One; Two; Three</ListItems>
          </CustomField>
        </CustomFields>
```

and

```
    <Document>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>3 Page Purchase Contract Template - test </Name>
      <!--PDFBytes>base64Binary</PDFBytes-->
      <!--TransformPdfFields>true</TransformPdfFields-->
      <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
        <DocumentFields>
          <DocumentField>
            <Name>FullName</Name>
            <Value>John W Smith</Value>
          </DocumentField>
        </DocumentFields>
    </Document>
```

In the code, even in different places, I don't get errors but nothing happens either. There is no information filled in - This is my sample XML code so far - Security is fine - the envelope with the template is emailed - I cannot figure out what I am missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
<CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
  <EnvelopeInformation>
    <TransactionID></TransactionID>
    <Asynchronous>false</Asynchronous>
    <AccountId>123</AccountId>
    <EmailBlurb>Test CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms - Customized message goes here. This is good progress, need to complete building the script then integrate with SMS script. </EmailBlurb>
    <Subject>Test CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms</Subject>
    <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
            <CustomFields>
              <CustomField>
                <Name>Home Owner</Name>
                <Show>True</Show>
                <Required>True</Required>
                <Value>John W Smith</Value>
              </CustomField>
              <CustomField>
                <Name>Home Address</Name>
                <Show>True</Show>
                <Required>True</Required>
                <Value>123 Any Way Tempe, AZ 85082</Value>
              </CustomField>
              <!--CustomField>
                <Name>Custom Field List</Name>
                <Show>True</Show>
                <Required>True</Required>
                <Value />
                <CustomFieldType>List</CustomFieldType>
                <ListItems>One; Two; Three</ListItems>
              </CustomField-->
            </CustomFields>
    <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
    <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
    <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
    <EnforceSignerVisibility>false</EnforceSignerVisibility>
    <EnableWetSign>false</EnableWetSign>
    <AllowRecipientRecursion>true</AllowRecipientRecursion>
    <AllowMarkup>false</AllowMarkup>
  </EnvelopeInformation>
  <CompositeTemplates>
    <CompositeTemplate>
      <ServerTemplates>
        <ServerTemplate>
          <Sequence>1</Sequence>
          <TemplateID>123</TemplateID>
        </ServerTemplate>
      </ServerTemplates>
      <InlineTemplates>
        <InlineTemplate>
          <Sequence>2</Sequence>
          <Envelope>
            <Recipients>
              <Recipient>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <UserName>Home Owner Email</UserName>
                <Email>mm@mm.com</Email>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <AccessCode />
                <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Note />
                <RoleName>SignerOne</RoleName>
                <DefaultRecipient>true</DefaultRecipient>
              </Recipient>
            </Recipients>
            <Tabs>
              <Tab>
                <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                <PageNumber>3</PageNumber>
                <XPosition>12</XPosition>
                <YPosition>10</YPosition>
                <ScaleValue>1.00000</ScaleValue>
                <Type>SignHere</Type>
                <Name>SignHere</Name>
                <TabLabel>Sign Here 1</TabLabel>
                <Value />
                <CustomTabHeight>0</CustomTabHeight>
                <CustomTabRequired>false</CustomTabRequired>
                <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
                <CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</CustomTabDisableAutoSize>
                <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
                <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
              </Tab> 
            </Tabs>
            <Subject>Sample Form</Subject>
            <EmailBlurb />
            <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
            <EnableWetSign>true</EnableWetSign>
          </Envelope>
       </InlineTemplate>
      </InlineTemplates>
        <PDFMetaDataTemplate>
          <Sequence>3</Sequence>
        </PDFMetaDataTemplate>
        <Document>
          <ID>1</ID>
          <Name>3 Page Purchase Contract Powerform.doc.pdf</Name>
          <!--PDFBytes>base64Binary</PDFBytes-->
          <TransformPdfFields />
          <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
            <DocumentFields>
              <DocumentField>
                <Name>Address</Name>
                <Value>123 Any Way Tempe, AZ 85281</Value>
              </DocumentField>
            </DocumentFields>
        </Document>
    </CompositeTemplate>
  </CompositeTemplates>
   <ActivateEnvelope>true</ActivateEnvelope>
</CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Where are you checking the custom fields values, to verify if it was populated or not?

Answer (score 0):

Tazz602,

DocuSign terms can be a little misleading, Custom Fields are Sender only fields that don't get burnished to the visible document, aka metadata for data collection that the recipients can't change. Tabs | Secure Fields are visible and can be sender or recipient, editable or read-only and are burnished to the visible document unless they are fields for CarbonCopy users.

If you really mean Custom Fields (metadata filled in by the sender) or tabs filled in by sender or recipient (in this example, just signing tabs) then I suggest you look at below JSON example and then the XML below so that you will see how and where to set and to retrieve the different types of custom fields and tabs. Remember Recipient Custom fields are the oldest and are just an array of 3 of 100 characters, where envelope and document custom fields are an array of key-value pairs. It appears you are sending XML via SOAP yet the same rules apply and if you look at an envelope sent via REST by using SOAP you can see the actual XML format to send via SOAP as well.

Header

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA
```

**JSON**

```
    --AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
"emailBlurb": "Test for CEFTAF Lab 2 Custom Fields Recipient Fields Document Fields",
"emailSubject": "Test for Dev 201 Lab 2",
"status": "created",
"enforceSignerVisibility" : "true",
               "notification":{
              "useAccountDefaults":"false",
              "reminders":{
                 "reminderEnabled":"true",
                 "reminderDelay":"2",
                 "reminderFrequency":"2"
              },
              "expirations":{
                 "expireEnabled":"true",
                 "expireAfter":"15",
                 "expireWarn":"1"
              }
              }, 
"compositeTemplates": [{
"inlineTemplates": [{
"sequence": "1",
"customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      {
        "fieldId": "123",
        "name": "MYCustomID",
        "show": "false",
        "required": "false",
        "value": "myId012345"
      }
    ],
    "listCustomFields": [
      {
        "listItems": [
          "elementValue1","elementValue2","elementValue3"
        ],
        "fieldId": "1234",
        "name": "myArrayListofItems",
        "show": "false",
        "required": "false",
        "value": "3"
      }
    ]
  },

"documents": [{
"documentId": "1",
"name": "test1.txt",
      "documentFields": [
        {
          "name": "Test1",
          "value": "value for test1"
        }
      ],
},
            {
"documentId": "2",
"name": "test2.txt"
},
            {
"documentId": "3",
"name": "test3.txt"
}

            ],
"recipients": {
            "carbonCopies": [
                            {
                                "email": "dsproservedemosoap01+Testcc@gmail.com",
                                "name": "David Grigsby (see all but 3 document)",
                                "recipientId": "3",
                                "routingOrder": "3"
                            },
                            {
                                "email": "dsproservedemosoap01+Testcc1@gmail.com",
                                "name": "David Grigsby (see all)",
                                "recipientId": "4",
                                "routingOrder": "4"
                            }
                            ],
"signers": [{
"recipientId": "1",
"customFields": [
  "Recip 1 ID 1234"
],
"name": "David Grigsby (Sees all)",
"email": "dsproservedemosoap01+Test1@gmail.com", 
                    "routingOrder": "1",
                    "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                      "anchorString": "Sign1",
                      "tabLabel": "Sign Here 1"
                      }]
                    }
},
                {
"recipientId": "2",
"name": "David Grigsby (sees all but page 2)",
"email": "david.grigsby@example.com", 
                    "requireSignOnPaper": "true",
                    "routingOrder": "2",
                    "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                      "anchorString": "Sign2",
                      "tabLabel": "Sign Here 2"
                      }]
                    }
}
                ]
}
}]
}]
}

--AAA
Content-Type: application/txt
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test1.txt"; documentid=1

Test Document 1 

Sign1 Here _______________________________    Custom1 Approve:



Sign2 Here _______________________________    Custom2 Approve:


--AAA
Content-Type: application/txt
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test2.txt"; documentid=2

Test Document 2

Sign1 Here _______________________________

--AAA
Content-Type: application/txt
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test3.txt"; documentid=3

Test Document 3

No Tabs for anyone means visbile to all by default unless excluded

--AAA--
```

**XML**
GET - REST

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/999999/envelopes/35f51755-5945-4db1-a376-bf5ce7fb4dbf/custom_fields.xml

```
<customFields xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<listCustomFields>
    <listCustomField>
        <fieldId>210499477</fieldId>
        <name>myArrayListofItems</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <show>false</show>
        <value>3</value>
        <listItems xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <a:string>elementValue1</a:string>
            <a:string>elementValue2</a:string>
            <a:string>elementValue3</a:string>
        </listItems>
    </listCustomField>
</listCustomFields>
<textCustomFields>
    <textCustomField>
        <fieldId>210499476</fieldId>
        <name>MYCustomID</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <show>false</show>
        <value>myId012345</value>
    </textCustomField>
</textCustomFields>
```

SOAP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/RequestEnvelopeResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:40ffda2d-b9f9-423a-8e39-74dac07cf994</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:24dc8bbd-92a0-4dcc-b517-6a3aac69d596</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6ca93662-5aad-4cc0-92ad-f614e4aeb225">
                <wsu:Created>2017-12-05T16:34:20Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2017-12-05T16:39:20Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RequestEnvelopeResponse xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
            <RequestEnvelopeResult>
                <AccountId>46d46020-570f-9999-8f02-c9859f65fc45</AccountId>
                <Documents>
                    <Document>
                        <ID>1</ID>
                        <Name>test1.txt</Name>
                        <PDFBytes>AA==</PDFBytes>
                        <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
                    </Document>
                    <Document>
                        <ID>2</ID>
                        <Name>test2.txt</Name>
                        <PDFBytes>AA==</PDFBytes>
                        <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
                    </Document>
                    <Document>
                        <ID>3</ID>
                        <Name>test3.txt</Name>
                        <PDFBytes>AA==</PDFBytes>
                        <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
                    </Document>
                </Documents>
                <Recipients>
                    <Recipient>
                        <ID>1</ID>
                        <UserName>David Grigsby (Sees all)</UserName>
                        <Email>dsproservedemosoap01+Test1@gmail.com</Email>
                        <Type>Signer</Type>
                        <AccessCode />
                        <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
                        <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                        <Note />
                    </Recipient>
                    <Recipient>
                        <ID>2</ID>
                        <UserName>David Grigsby (sees all but page 2)</UserName>
                        <Email>david.grigsby@example.com</Email>
                        <Type>Signer</Type>
                        <AccessCode />
                        <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
                        <RoutingOrder>2</RoutingOrder>
                        <Note />
                    </Recipient>
                    <Recipient>
                        <ID>3</ID>
                        <UserName>David Grigsby (see all but 3 document)</UserName>
                        <Email>dsproservedemosoapui+Testcc@gmail.com</Email>
                        <Type>CarbonCopy</Type>
                        <AccessCode />
                        <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
                        <RoutingOrder>3</RoutingOrder>
                        <Note />
                    </Recipient>
                    <Recipient>
                        <ID>4</ID>
                        <UserName>David Grigsby (see all)</UserName>
                        <Email>dsproservedemosoap01+Testcc1@gmail.com</Email>
                        <Type>CarbonCopy</Type>
                        <AccessCode />
                        <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
                        <RoutingOrder>4</RoutingOrder>
                        <Note />
                    </Recipient>
                </Recipients>
                <Tabs>
                    <Tab>
                        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                        <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                        <XPosition>70</XPosition>
                        <YPosition>49</YPosition>
                        <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                        <AnchorTabItem>
                            <AnchorTabString>Sign1</AnchorTabString>
                            <Unit>Pixels</Unit>
                        </AnchorTabItem>
                        <Type>SignHere</Type>
                        <Name>SignHere</Name>
                        <TabLabel>Sign Here 1</TabLabel>
                        <Value />
                        <CustomTabRequired>false</CustomTabRequired>
                        <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab>
                        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                        <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                        <XPosition>350</XPosition>
                        <YPosition>92</YPosition>
                        <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                        <AnchorTabItem>
                            <AnchorTabString>Custom1 Approve:</AnchorTabString>
                            <Unit>Pixels</Unit>
                        </AnchorTabItem>
                        <Type>Approve</Type>
                        <Name>Please Approve this</Name>
                        <TabLabel>Custom API Approve_1</TabLabel>
                        <Value />
                        <CustomTabWidth>125</CustomTabWidth>
                        <CustomTabHeight>39</CustomTabHeight>
                        <CustomTabRequired>false</CustomTabRequired>
                        <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
                        <CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</CustomTabDisableAutoSize>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab>
                        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                        <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
                        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                        <XPosition>70</XPosition>
                        <YPosition>92</YPosition>
                        <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                        <AnchorTabItem>
                            <AnchorTabString>Sign2</AnchorTabString>
                            <Unit>Pixels</Unit>
                        </AnchorTabItem>
                        <Type>SignHere</Type>
                        <Name>SignHere</Name>
                        <TabLabel>Sign Here 2</TabLabel>
                        <Value />
                        <CustomTabRequired>false</CustomTabRequired>
                        <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab>
                        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                        <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
                        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                        <XPosition>350</XPosition>
                        <YPosition>135</YPosition>
                        <ScaleValue>1</ScaleValue>
                        <AnchorTabItem>
                            <AnchorTabString>Custom2 Approve:</AnchorTabString>
                            <Unit>Pixels</Unit>
                        </AnchorTabItem>
                        <Type>Approve</Type>
                        <Name>Please Approve this</Name>
                        <TabLabel>Custom API Approve_2</TabLabel>
                        <Value />
                        <CustomTabWidth>125</CustomTabWidth>
                        <CustomTabHeight>39</CustomTabHeight>
                        <CustomTabRequired>false</CustomTabRequired>
                        <CustomTabLocked>false</CustomTabLocked>
                        <CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</CustomTabDisableAutoSize>
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
                <Subject>Test for Dev 201 Lab 2</Subject>
                <EmailBlurb>Test for CEFTAF Lab 2 Custom Fields Recipient Fields Document Fields</EmailBlurb>
                <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
                <CustomFields>
                    <CustomField>
                        <Name>MYCustomID</Name>
                        <Show>False</Show>
                        <Required>False</Required>
                        <Value>myId012345</Value>
                    </CustomField>
                    <CustomField>
                        <Name>myArrayListofItems</Name>
                        <Show>False</Show>
                        <Required>False</Required>
                        <Value>3</Value>
                        <CustomFieldType>List</CustomFieldType>
                        <ListItems>elementValue1;elementValue2;elementValue3</ListItems>
                    </CustomField>
                </CustomFields>
                <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
                <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
                <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
                <Notification>
                    <Reminders>
                        <ReminderEnabled>true</ReminderEnabled>
                        <ReminderDelay>2</ReminderDelay>
                        <ReminderFrequency>2</ReminderFrequency>
                    </Reminders>
                    <Expirations>
                        <ExpireEnabled>true</ExpireEnabled>
                        <ExpireAfter>15</ExpireAfter>
                        <ExpireWarn>1</ExpireWarn>
                    </Expirations>
                </Notification>
                <EnforceSignerVisibility>false</EnforceSignerVisibility>
                <AllowMarkup>false</AllowMarkup>
                <AllowReassign>true</AllowReassign>
            </RequestEnvelopeResult>
        </RequestEnvelopeResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I will give it a try and let you know.  I appreciate it!!! I had a feelings tabs might have more to do with it but the verbiage threw me off.

Comment: If this helped could you mark this as the answer please or let me know what is unclear - thanks

Comment: @Tazz602 any update you can provide in this new year?